Excel VBA print range partially based on a formula
I would like to set a print range partially based on a cell reference.
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$G$1000"

In the above example, I would replace the 1000 with a value in a named range (MaxRow)
I would normally use Indirect (in a non-VBA formula) to change the value, but I know VBA handles indirect differently (but don't remember exactly how).
I have tried the below but get a runtime error 1004 where it is thinking I have a formula not a reference.
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$G$" & MaxRow
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$G$" & "MaxRow"


"$A$1:$G$" & Range("MaxRow").Value

Thanks BigBen; I was close but yet oh-so-far.
